# STM32F103 blue pill - problems related to blinking led bare metal

Tags: c, loops, arm, embedded, bluepill

I come across a problem when trying to run this code in order to blink the built-in LED (located at PC13) on the blue pill board (STM32F103C8, ARM Cortex M3):

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"                  // Device header

#define max 1000000

int main(void){
    RCC->APB2ENR |= 1<<4;
    GPIOC->CRH &= 0xFF0FFFF;//clear the necessary bit 
    GPIOC->CRH |= 0x00300000;//set the necessary bit
    GPIOC->ODR &= ~(1<<13);//turn PC_13 ON
        while(1){
                    GPIOC->ODR |= 1<<13;//off
                    for(unsigned int i = 0;i < max;++i);
                    GPIOA->ODR &= ~(1<<13);//on
                    for(unsigned int i = 0;i < max;++i);
    }
}
```

.
Here I receive some errors and I don't know why:
[image]

Could anybody help me?
Also, when I declare the unsigned integer "i" within the while loop all goes fine, but even though, nothing happens, the LED still does not blink. Here is the modified code:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"                  // Device header

#define max 1000000

int main(void){
    RCC->APB2ENR |= 1<<4;
    GPIOC->CRH &= 0xFF0FFFF;//clear the necessary bit 
    GPIOC->CRH |= 0x00300000;//set the necessary bit
    GPIOC->ODR &= ~(1<<13);//turn PC_13 ON
        while(1){
                    unsigned int i;
                    GPIOC->ODR |= 1<<13;//off
                    for(i = 0;i < max;++i);
                    GPIOA->ODR &= ~(1<<13);//on
                    for(i = 0;i < max;++i);
    }
}
```

.
Moreover, I tried another trick, to declare the integer "i" outside the loop, like here:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"                  // Device header

#define max 1000000

int main(void){
    RCC->APB2ENR |= 1<<4;
    GPIOC->CRH &= 0xFF0FFFF;//clear the necessary bit 
    GPIOC->CRH |= 0x00300000;//set the necessary bit
    GPIOC->ODR &= ~(1<<13);//turn PC_13 ON
        unsigned int i;
        while(1){
                    GPIOC->ODR |= 1<<13;//off
                    for(i = 0;i < max;++i);
                    GPIOA->ODR &= ~(1<<13);//on
                    for(i = 0;i < max;++i);
    }
}
```

. Then, I've received the next error message:
[image]
. Now, the question is why?
Please help me.

Comment: This seems like you're compiling with the C89 standard. Back then variables had to be declared at the start of a block.

Comment: Note you need a volatile on that variable.  Otherwise the loop gets optimized away and there is no delay between on and off.  If you put it on a scope you would see the signal change, but not enough to be visible (maybe if you make the room dark, but this frequency is probably too fast)

Comment: Thank you. Good point, that was why I encountered the other bug, now everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the uVision project configuration dialog C/C++ tab, select "use C99".

ISO C90 dies not allow declaration of variables in either a `for` statement or following non -declaritive code in a statement block.

Alternatively move the declaration to the top of the statement block in which it is required.  Better to use C99 though - it has been around long enough to be regarded as lowest common denominator standard I think!

Comment: Now the compile error disappeared, but I still have problems related to the blinking process. I cannot see the built-in LED blinking. It seems to be always off. Could you help me?

Comment: The iterator should be declared as volatile, this is the solution.